# Strange unit $kg/m$ - How to interpret?

Tags: general-relativity, units

We have a [publication](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0410078.pdf).

Page 4 in this publication. Cite:

> Note that the numerical value of $µ/c^{2}$, from Eq. (3) and the numbers
>   given above, is about $10^{−19}$ kg/m, emphasizing the extremely small
>   amount of mass in the rotating light cylinder in a realistic case...

How should be interpreted in this case, the unit $kg/m$?

kg is the unit weight of the cylinder. But why /m?

What defines m? Is it a perimeter of the cylinder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an infinitely long cylinder.  You can only express mass per unit length (they chose m, which seems fairly reasonable).

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question but I do not understand. We have a cylinder. We also have a specific length [m = meter]. What determines this length in cylinder? The height of the cylinder? The radius of the cylinder? Something else?

Comment: @Aurelio The cylinder is theoretical and goes on forever.  Therefore it's mass would also be infinite.  That said, if you were to cut out 1m of it it would weigh $10^{-19} kg $.  Another way of saying that is it weighs $10^{-19} kg $ per metre of length.  Since it's length is infinite this is the best way to express the mass.

Comment: @Aurelio In the work store you can buy drain tubing at 10 € per meter. You don't ask them how many euros of tubing they have on stock in total - they would say infinitely much (they can always order more). That's not relevant. The only thing that's relevant is the amount that you want to buy. So they sell it in € **per meter** of length to make that easy to calculate. --- Now replace € with kg and read again.

Answer (score 0):

In your citation (you really should be extracting the relevant bit), $\mu$ is defined as an energy per unit length.  This gives it the units:

$[{\mu}] = \frac{\rm J}{\rm m} = \frac{\rm kg\cdot m^{2}/s^{2}}{m} = \frac{\rm kg \cdot m}{\rm s^{2}}$

Since the speed of light has units of m/s, the units of $\mu / c^{2}$ are kg/m.  This would describe a mass per unit length.

Answer (score -2):

kg/m - mass per unit length...